# Scroll to top when using Switch (react-router)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

When navigating from one page to another, I would like the user to be automatically scrolled to the top, i.e. `scrollTo(0, 0)`.

According to the `react-router` [docs on scroll restoration](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/scroll-restoration) the recommended approach is to setup a component `ScrollToTop` and wrap your routes within this.

While this works well and the user is scrolled to the top for any route nested within the `ScrollToTop` component, if the component is placed within a `Switch` component, the `Switch` does not function like a Switch any longer; meaning that it will render all routes that it matches instead of the first one.

Alternatively, placing the `ScrollToTop` outside of the `Switch`, it no longer scrolls the user to the top.

Version: `react-router-v4`

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure specifically about the scrolling, but you can attach a listener to `browserHistory` which may be an easy way to do this (I don't think `onUpdate` works with v4):

```
const browserHistory = createBrowserHistory();

browserHistory.listen((location, action) => {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});

<Router history={browserHistory} />
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: You should also reset keyboard focus at the same time as scrolling to top. I wrote a thing to take care of it: https://github.com/oaf-project/oaf-react-router

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue what i did was Whenever the  is updated it will take the user to the `scrollTo(0,0)`

```
<Router onUpdate={() => window.scrollTo(0, 0)} history={createBrowserHistory()}>
  ...
</Router
```

If above does not work :

In **react-router-v4** [scroll Restoration](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/scroll-restoration)

This is straightforward to handle with a  component that will scroll the window up on every navigation, make sure to wrap it in withRouter to give it access to the router’s props:

```
 componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.location !== prevProps.location) {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0)
    }
  }

  render() {
    return this.props.children
  }
}
```

Then render it at the top of your app, but below Router

```
const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <ScrollToTop>
      <App/>
    </ScrollToTop>
  </Router>
)
```

Above code is copied from React-Router [web guides](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/scroll-restoration)

Comment: onUpdate does not work with v4 , I have updated it with another solution

Comment: Other solution does not work with Switch from my experience as I explained in my original post.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this using the `react-router-v4` scroll Restoration and placing the ScrollToTop outside of the `Switch`. Also remember to use `withRouter` otherwise it won't work.

Comment: thats exactly what i suggested in my post below to use scroll Restoration with 'withRouter' , Glad to know its solved

Comment: My issue was with the `Switch` which you didn't include. But all is good now, thanks.

Comment: This does not work when returning to previous visited pages. Any advice? Thank you in advance

Comment: If you are referring to back/forward navigation, that intentionally doesn't trigger a scroll to top as this is the best practice implemented by browsers. If you wish to scroll, then you need to move your ScrollToTop to fire `scrollTo` instead of only when the location changes.